# Bootstrap css based on environment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to apply css property (margin-top) on a bootstrap column but only for the lg environment. What is the proper way to do that?

I found a solution using javascript but i was wondering if there is pure css solution.

I am using bootstrap 3.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSS media query. 1200 pixels is the Bootstrap breakpoint for `lg`, so it would look like this.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 

  #myCol {
      margin-top:20px;
  }

}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/127137

If you want the CSS to be applied at other "sizes" take a look at the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) to see the different breakpoints.